# Jammit append query string to end of file on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, jammit

Jammit does not append a query string to files in production environments after compiling all the assets.

This presents caching problems for me since my web server uses query strings to bust the cache.

How can I use jammit (or another tool) to properly uglify, concatenate, and append a query string?

Comment: can you provide more details please?

Comment: we use Jammit without any problem, and it's good tool. I'd like to help if I know details and logs

Comment: `<script src="/assets/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` is what is produced by jammit in production. I need there to be a query string in there otherwise that file is going to be cached for everybody. In development that query string exists.

Comment: Do you pass something on this file source appending params?

Comment: Rails appends query strings with `javascript_include_tag` or `image_tag`. Jammit doesn't add them here using `include_javascripts`

Comment: what means "appends query strings"? are you talking about timestamp?

Comment: Yeah. I have resolved the issue. It was isolated to my project. Thanks for you time.

Comment: Can you explain what the issue was? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: We moved to sprockets and are infinitely happier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a response in case anyone else runs into this.

Jammit rewrites relative urls when concatenating css files. This is necessary because relative paths in css are relative to the file containing the path, so when css files are concatenated, these paths need to be rewritten. During this rewriting process Jammit seems to remove query params. To my understanding, to work around this you'll need to either 1) use absolute urls in your css files 2) patch Jammit.